# Include before_body only to some chapters in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to include a before_body only to some of the chapters in bookdown?
I tried to write a yaml header for the chapters in which I want to insert the before_body block but nothing showed up

```
--- 
bookdown::gitbook:
  includes: 
    before_body: includes/myblock.html
---
```

Comment: Just for the record, this question was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/265#issuecomment-538309548

Comment: For info, I did it manually using `sed` after compiling the book.